# How do you parse this JSON data?

Tags: json, vb.net

I have this `JSON` data that I would like to parse but I'm not sure how to go about it.
Here's the `JSON`:

```
{
   "input":{
      "lat":32.761125,
      "lon":-96.791339
   },
   "results":[
      {
         "block_fips":"481130204001105",
         "bbox":[
            -96.79587,
            32.753273,
            -96.787714,
            32.76218
         ],
         "county_fips":"48113",
         "county_name":"Dallas",
         "state_fips":"48",
         "state_code":"TX",
         "state_name":"Texas",
         "block_pop_2015":2,
         "amt":"AMT004",
         "bea":"BEA127",
         "bta":"BTA101",
         "cma":"CMA009",
         "eag":"EAG005",
         "ivm":"IVM009",
         "mea":"MEA032",
         "mta":"MTA007",
         "pea":"PEA008",
         "rea":"REA005",
         "rpc":"RPC004",
         "vpc":"VPC004"
      }
   ]
}
```

I used the Visual Studio tool, `Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste as JSON classes`, to convert this `JSON` in classes and it gave me this class structure:

```
Public Class Rootobject
    Public Property input As Input
    Public Property results() As Result
End Class

Public Class Input
    Public Property lat As Single
    Public Property lon As Single
End Class

Public Class Result
    Public Property block_fips As String
    Public Property bbox() As Single
    Public Property county_fips As String
    Public Property county_name As String
    Public Property state_fips As String
    Public Property state_code As String
    Public Property state_name As String
    Public Property block_pop_2015 As Integer
    Public Property amt As String
    Public Property bea As String
    Public Property bta As String
    Public Property cma As String
    Public Property eag As String
    Public Property ivm As String
    Public Property mea As String
    Public Property mta As String
    Public Property pea As String
    Public Property rea As String
    Public Property rpc As String
    Public Property vpc As String
End Class
```

So then what I did to try and parse the data is:

```
Dim MyJSON As String = JsonAbove
Dim jss As New JavaScriptSerializer()
Dim dict = jss.Deserialize(Of Result)(rawresp)
MsgBox(dict.state_name)
```

All I get is a blank MessageBox with no results.
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Try Dim dict = jss.Deserialize(Of Rootobject)(rawresp) instead Of Result

Comment: Would I then get the result with something like `dict.results.state_name` ? Because its saying that the result is not supported for deserialization of an array

Comment: dict.results[0].state_name

Comment: Or `Dim state As String = jss.Deserialize(Of Rootobject)(rawresp).results(0).state_name`

Comment: Hi @Jimi - Trying your way produces the following error `'Public Property results As Result' has no parameters and its return type cannot be indexed`

Comment: Same error is produced even if I try `MsgBox(dict.results(0).state_name)`

Comment: Could you dump JavaScriptSerializer and use Newtonsoft.Json instead? Btw, what I posted and what (of course, it's the same) Akshay Gaonkar posted work. When JavaScriptSerializer works. Which may not be.

Comment: Sure, is there an example of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use List Of Objects instead of array in your class. I have done two changes One in the rootobject for results and other in the result class for bbox

```
Public Class Rootobject
    Public Property input As Input
    Public Property results As List(Of Result)
End Class

Public Class Input
    Public Property lat As Single
    Public Property lon As Single
End Class

Public Class Result
    Public Property block_fips As String
    Public Property bbox As List(Of Single)
    Public Property county_fips As String
    Public Property county_name As String
    Public Property state_fips As String
    Public Property state_code As String
    Public Property state_name As String
    Public Property block_pop_2015 As Integer
    Public Property amt As String
    Public Property bea As String
    Public Property bta As String
    Public Property cma As String
    Public Property eag As String
    Public Property ivm As String
    Public Property mea As String
    Public Property mta As String
    Public Property pea As String
    Public Property rea As String
    Public Property rpc As String
    Public Property vpc As String
End Class
```

Then access the properties

```
  Dim jss As New JavaScriptSerializer()
  Dim dict = jss.Deserialize(Of Rootobject)(MyJSON)
  MsgBox(dict.results.FirstOrDefault().state_name)
```

Comment: List Of Object worked perfectly fine. Thank you, I never seem to have good luck with JSON or XML

Answer (score 1):

Same, using the `Newtonsoft.Json` namespace.

The classes properties have being assigned new names, using a `<JsonProperty>` attribute.
Also, the **`Results`** property is modified to return a `List(Of Result)`.

The deserialization is pretty simple and straightforward:
You can use the Visual Studio `NuGet Package Manager` to install `Newtonsoft.Json`.

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json

Dim latlonResults As RootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of RootObject)(JSON)
Dim state As String = latlonResults.Results(0).StateName
```

or access a property directly while deserializing:

```
Dim state As String = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of RootObject)(JSON).Results(0).StateName
```

*Refactored* classes:

```
Public Class RootObject 
    <JsonProperty("input")>
    Public Property Input() As Input

    <JsonProperty("results")>
    Public Property Results() As List(Of Result)
End Class

Public Class Input
    <JsonProperty("lat")>
    Public Property Lat() As Double

    <JsonProperty("lon")>
    Public Property Lon() As Double
End Class

Public Class Result
    <JsonProperty("block_fips")>
    Public Property BlockFips() As String

    <JsonProperty("bbox")>
    Public Property Bbox() As List(Of Double)

    <JsonProperty("county_fips")>
    Public Property CountyFips() As Long

    <JsonProperty("county_name")>
    Public Property CountyName() As String

    <JsonProperty("state_fips")>
    Public Property StateFips() As Long

    <JsonProperty("state_code")>
    Public Property StateCode() As String

    <JsonProperty("state_name")>
    Public Property StateName() As String

    <JsonProperty("block_pop_2015")>
    Public Property BlockPop2015() As Long

    <JsonProperty("amt")>
    Public Property Amt() As String

    <JsonProperty("bea")>
    Public Property Bea() As String

    <JsonProperty("bta")>
    Public Property Bta() As String

    <JsonProperty("cma")>
    Public Property Cma() As String

    <JsonProperty("eag")>
    Public Property Eag() As String

    <JsonProperty("ivm")>
    Public Property Ivm() As String

    <JsonProperty("mea")>
    Public Property Mea() As String

    <JsonProperty("mta")>
    Public Property Mta() As String

    <JsonProperty("pea")>
    Public Property Pea() As String

    <JsonProperty("rea")>
    Public Property Rea() As String

    <JsonProperty("rpc")>
    Public Property Rpc() As String

    <JsonProperty("vpc")>
    Public Property Vpc() As String
End Class
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer as well. I wish I can mark both as the accepted answer, but at least it will help someone else in the future if they happen to see this post!

Comment: Sure, I posted it for your conveniece first and, of course, for anyone else interested. About the Visual Studio tool: it's a really simplified tool. You may not get  good results when the JSON is slightly more complex. You could use some on-line services. For VB.Net, for example, [JSON Utils](https://jsonutils.com/). But I suggest  [QuickType](https://app.quicktype.io/#l=cs&r=json2csharp): it doesn't have a VB.Net JSON converter, but it's really, well,  precise. Also, [JSON Formatter & Validator](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/), it's a JSON validator/prettify tool.